# Question about "work" done on a sphere to empty all the water out?

Tags: calculus, integration

Q:
Suppose a spherical tank is full of water, calculate the work required to drain it out completely, if the radius 3ft and there is a spout of 1ft. (water density $62.5 Ilbs/ft^{3}$)

My solution:

I draw a picture drawing the sphere laying on the x-axis.

(get a generic cross-sectional slice)

$V_{slice} = π·r^{2}·h$

$V_{slice} = π·r^{2}·dy$

So, now I have to find out what 'r' is.
'r' is the same as the isolated 'x' of the equation of a circle.
So,

$x^{2} + y^{2} = 9$

$x = +/-\sqrt{9 - y^{2}}$

so,

$V_{slice} = π·(9 - y^{2})·dy$

and for force:

$F_{slice} = (62.5)·π·(9 - y^{2})$

And no displacement, which I think I have wrong.

$displacement = (7 - y)$

Therefore we only integrate where there is water, so limits of integration would range from 0 to 6.

So altogether:
$W = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{6} (62.5)·π·(9-y^{2})·(7 - y)dy$

Comment: You're close: It sounds as if you have the tank sitting on the origin, stretching from $y = 0$ to $y = 6$. On the other hand, the radius function $x = \sqrt{9 - y^{2}}$ presumes the _center_ of the tank is at the origin. There are (at least) two ways to fix this discrepancy; I'd be inclined to put the origin at the center of the tank.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you, why is it better to put the origin at the center of the tank?

Comment: If the origin is at the center, the limits are symmetric ($y = -3$ to $y = 3$) and $y(9 - y^{2})$ is odd, and hence integrates to $0$. If you place the sphere between $y = 0$ and $y = 6$, you have $x^{2} + (y - 3)^{2} = 9$ and the symmetry is less apparent (unless you substitute $u = y - 3$, which amounts to sliding your coordinates so the origin is at the center).